# Unattended Windows 7 Installation Error

Tags: windows-7

I'm getting an error code at step 4 and at the end it tells me that i have to restart the whole process. I'm new to this and my troubleshooting skills are practically null.

This happens both in Virtualbox and on a physical system.

I'd really appreciate any and all help I can receive.

Here are the contents of the autounattend file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<unattend xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:unattend">
    <settings pass="windowsPE">
    <component name="Microsoft-Windows-International-Core-WinPE" processorArchitecture="x86" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" language="neutral" versionScope="nonSxS" xmlns:wcm="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WMIConfig/2002/State" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
        <SetupUILanguage>
            <UILanguage>en-US</UILanguage>
        </SetupUILanguage>
        <InputLocale>en-US</InputLocale>
        <SystemLocale>en-US</SystemLocale>
        <UILanguage>en-US</UILanguage>
        <UserLocale>en-US</UserLocale>
    </component>
    <component name="Microsoft-Windows-Setup" processorArchitecture="x86" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" language="neutral" versionScope="nonSxS" xmlns:wcm="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WMIConfig/2002/State" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
        <DiskConfiguration>
            <Disk wcm:action="add">
                <CreatePartitions>
                    <CreatePartition wcm:action="add">
                        <Order>1</Order>
                        <Size>300</Size>
                        <Type>Primary</Type>
                    </CreatePartition>
                    <CreatePartition wcm:action="add">
                        <Extend>true</Extend>
                        <Order>2</Order>
                        <Type>Primary</Type>
                    </CreatePartition>
                </CreatePartitions>
                <ModifyPartitions>
                    <ModifyPartition wcm:action="add">
                        <Active>true</Active>
                        <Format>NTFS</Format>
                        <Label>System</Label>
                        <Order>1</Order>
                        <PartitionID>1</PartitionID>
                    </ModifyPartition>
                    <ModifyPartition wcm:action="add">
                        <Format>NTFS</Format>
                        <Label>Windows</Label>
                        <Order>2</Order>
                        <PartitionID>2</PartitionID>
                    </ModifyPartition>
                </ModifyPartitions>
                <DiskID>0</DiskID>
                <WillWipeDisk>true</WillWipeDisk>
            </Disk>
            <WillShowUI>OnError</WillShowUI>
        </DiskConfiguration>
        <ImageInstall>
            <OSImage>
                <InstallFrom>
                    <MetaData wcm:action="add">
                        <Key>/IMAGE/NAME</Key>
                        <Value>Windows 7 HOMEPREMIUM</Value>
                    </MetaData>
                </InstallFrom>
                <InstallTo>
                    <DiskID>0</DiskID>
                    <PartitionID>2</PartitionID>
                </InstallTo>
                <InstallToAvailablePartition>false</InstallToAvailablePartition>
                <WillShowUI>OnError</WillShowUI>
            </OSImage>
        </ImageInstall>
        <UserData>
            <ProductKey>
                <Key>FJ82H-XT6CR-J8D7P-XQJJ2-GPDD4</Key>
                <WillShowUI>OnError</WillShowUI>
            </ProductKey>
            <AcceptEula>true</AcceptEula>
            <FullName>Theo</FullName>
        </UserData>
    </component>
</settings>
<settings pass="specialize">
    <component name="Microsoft-Windows-Shell-Setup" processorArchitecture="x86" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" language="neutral" versionScope="nonSxS" xmlns:wcm="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WMIConfig/2002/State" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
        <ProductKey>FJ82H-XT6CR-J8D7P-XQJJ2-GPDD4</ProductKey>
        <ComputerName>Theo&apos;s PC</ComputerName>
        <TimeZone>E. Europe Standard Time</TimeZone>
    </component>
</settings>
<settings pass="oobeSystem">
    <component name="Microsoft-Windows-Shell-Setup" processorArchitecture="x86" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" language="neutral" versionScope="nonSxS" xmlns:wcm="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WMIConfig/2002/State" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
        <OOBE>
            <HideEULAPage>true</HideEULAPage>
            <HideWirelessSetupInOOBE>true</HideWirelessSetupInOOBE>
            <NetworkLocation>Home</NetworkLocation>
            <ProtectYourPC>1</ProtectYourPC>
        </OOBE>
        <UserAccounts>
            <AdministratorPassword>
                <Value>bwByAGwAYQBuAGQAbwBBAGQAbQBpAG4AaQBzAHQAcgBhAHQAbwByAFAAYQBzAHMAdwBvAHIAZAA=</Value>
                <PlainText>false</PlainText>
            </AdministratorPassword>
            <LocalAccounts>
                <LocalAccount wcm:action="add">
                    <Password>
                        <Value>bwByAGwAYQBuAGQAbwBQAGEAcwBzAHcAbwByAGQA</Value>
                        <PlainText>false</PlainText>
                    </Password>
                    <Description>Built in Account</Description>
                    <DisplayName>Theadora</DisplayName>
                    <Group>Administrators</Group>
                    <Name>Theo</Name>
                </LocalAccount>
            </LocalAccounts>
        </UserAccounts>
        <TimeZone>E. Europe Standard Time</TimeZone>
    </component>
</settings>
<cpi:offlineImage cpi:source="catalog://guanno/users/kza/desktop/new folder/flat/sources/install_windows 7 homepremium.clg" xmlns:cpi="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:cpi" />
</unattend>
```

Thanks for reading and for any feedback :)

Comment: What's the actual error code you're getting?  What have you tried already in attempts to correct it?

Comment: The file you post is not complete so I can't check it in `Windows System Image Manager`. The last line of the file should be </xml> What are you using to create the file?

Comment: Edited the code, now it's complete. It was missing just the '</unattend>' at the end; it has no </xml> as a last line, should i add it?
I used Windows System Image Manager to create the file and Deployment Tools Command Prompt to recreate the image the ISO.
Also i know that the key is not for the version that i am trying ti install but i believe that is not the issue. It is a key given out for test purposes and the error message that it sends out is not related to it as far as i can tell.
Running a virtual installation now an i will post the results.
Thanks guys :)

Comment: First error:
    Windows could not parse or process the unattend answer file for pass [specialize]. The settings specified in the answer file cannot be applied. The error was detected while processing settings for component [Microsoft-Windows-Shell-Setup].

    Second error:
    The computer restarted unexpectedly or encountered an unexpected error. Windows instalation cannot procede. To install Windows, click "OK" to restart the computer, and then restart the installation.

Comment: A quick question:
    The target machine for installation is a laptop running a x86 intel cpu.
    The machine that i am working on is running a x64 intel cpu.
    I used winpe_x86 to create the file. Was i right to do so?

Comment: @Kza Keep in mind you just shared your passwords with the world.

Comment: @Steven, thank you but they are encrypted right? 
Anyway the security of this computer is not important but thank you for the heads up :)

Comment: @Kza No, the passwords are simply encoded.  https://www.base64decode.org/ (Hint: Florida)

Comment: @Steven, good to know, thank you (Hint: Bloom)

Comment: @kza the key is the issue - did you try it manually?

Comment: @albal, i just did a manual installation. The key was no good. After that i removed the key altogether (left the fields blank) and tried to install it that way. The same 2 errors occurred.

Answer (score 2):

According to [Configuring KMS Clients](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff793406.aspx)

`FJ82H-XT6CR-J8D7P-XQJJ2-GPDD4` is a key for Windows 7 Professional.

But you are requesting to install `Windows 7 HOMEPREMIUM` in your `autounattend.xml` file.